# Electron clipboard.writeHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, electron, clipboard

I wanted to access the clipboard using the Electron clipboard module. I wrote:

```
const clipboard = require("electron")
// add an eventlister on my button to copy the innerHTML of div "content" 
document.getElementById("copy").addEventListener("click", () => {
         const code = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML
         // the line below complains: "Uncaught TypeError: clipboard.writeHTML is  not a function"
         clipboard.writeHTML(code)
         
     })
```

I was wondering why and couldn't figure it out for a whole day. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clipboard is not the default export from `electron`. You need:

```
const { clipboard } = require('electron')
```

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/clipboard

And [MDN on export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Comment: Issue fixed. Thank you so much!